# Incorrect title of Stack header back button in Expo Router

Tags: reactjs, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

I am working on a React Native project using Expo Router and have encountered an issue with the title displayed on the "Back" button.

**Navigation Structure:**

My navigation structure is as follows:

in /app

```
_layout.tsx <Stack />
  (tabs)
    _layout <Tabs />
    home
      _layout <Stack />
      index <- when I router.navigate('/list/[id]') from here
list
  [id] <- to here I have an incorrect header back title
```

[(tabs) header back button title instead home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KychH.png)

**The Issue:**

When I navigate from the home Tabs.Screen to the list item screen, I expect to see the title `home`, but instead, it shows `(tabs)`.

**Code**

`/app/_layout.tsx`

```js
export const unstable_settings = {
    initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
};

export default function RootLayout() {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" />
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

`/app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx`

```js
export default function TabsLayout() {
    return (
        <Tabs>
            <Tabs.Screen name="home" />
            <Tabs.Screen name="about" />
        </Tabs>
    );
}
```

`/app/_layout/home/index.tsx`

```js
export default function HomeScreen() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    // Navigation to Item
    const navigateToItem = () => {
        navigation.navigate('/item/1');
    };

    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Go to Item 1" onPress={navigateToMeal} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

**What I've Tried**

I tried to give a title to each screen I have

- Tried navigation without unstable_settings with the redirect in /app/index.tsx

How can I ensure that the title on the back button correctly reflects the previous screen's name in my navigation? Are there any specific behaviors in Expo Router that affect header management?

Will be grateful for any help! Thanks!

**My temporary solving**

I wrote a hook in each tab for detecting the current tab name, next, I set the title which I wanna use in the back button to redux store and call setOptions with this title in the tabs layout.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `(tabs)` stack item a title:

```
export const unstable_settings = {
    initialRouteName: '(tabs)',
};

export default function RootLayout() {
    return (
        <Stack>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="(tabs)"
                options={{
                    title: 'Home',
                }}
            />
        </Stack>
    );
}
```

This doesn't address the fact that the back button is not displaying the name of the previous tabs subscreen, since the navigation that is happening in this case is between stacks.